# Password is not able to type in command line while trying add npm package via command line

Tags: github, npm

I was trying to login to github-  npm login --registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com --scope=@phanatic
via command line. I could type  the user name. but I was not able to type the password.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OECEK.png)

I have tried to type / copy paste the password Git access token but it is not pasted or I couldn't type over there in the password field